# Adding URL link to a picture

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

So I have this carousel making my website 'fancy'. But I want to link the individual pictures to the websites it should got to once clicked on.

The following is my code:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
 <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/ncaa-bb-banner-1920x500 (1).png" alt="First slide" >
  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" >
    <h5 href="sportsevents.php">Sport Events</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added `href="sportsevents.php"` to the first `div`, `img` and the second `div`, but it doesn't seem to link up. Am I having a brain fart and missing something or is there something else I should do?

Comment: The `href` attribute isn't valid on a div or h5. You probably want an anchor, e.g. `<a>`

Comment: Inside each carousel-item div, create a <a> tag container ? Or with JavaScript, add a window location when you click on div ?

Comment: Of course!!! It is working like planned now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this and get desired result.

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
            <a href="sportsevents.php" target="_blank"><img class="d-block w-100" src="images/ncaa-bb-banner-1920x500 (1).png" alt="First slide" ></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" >
              <h5><a href="sportsevents.php" target="_blank">Sport Events</a></h5>
            </div>
          </div>
```